# Create click button event in loop

Tags: javascript, dom, closures

Im writing a simple script that supposted to change button value and then click it. Values of buttons comes from an array.

This is how I imagine it, how it supposted to work. Script supposted to take id from array, set attribute with this id and then click that button. This code doesn't work propably because of closures. It clicks just once.

```
var productList = ['43', '64', '68'];


for (var i = 0; i < productList.length; i++) {

  let btn = document.querySelector('.addProduct');
  btn.setAttribute('itemprop', productList[i]);
  btn.click();

}
```

Then I wrote something that should work in my opinion with closures, but it doesn't.

```
var funcs = [];

function changeProdBtnAndClick(i) {

  let btn = document.querySelector('.addProduct');
  btn.setAttribute('itemprop', productList[i]);
  btn.click();

}

for (var i = 0; i < productList.length; i++) {
  funcs[i] = changeProdBtnAndClick(i);
} 

for (var j = 0; j < productList.length; j++) {
  funcs[j]();                         
}
```

Using this code it also click just once and then I get an error

> Uncaught TypeError: funcs[j] is not a function

**EDITED**:
So I worked on my code, and added comment suggestion but it still doesn't work:

```
let funcs = [];

var changeProdBtnAndClick = function(i) {

  let btn = document.querySelector('.addProduct');
  btn.setAttribute('itemprop', productList[i]);
  btn.click();

  return 'added ' + productList[i];
}

for (var i = 0; i < productList.length; i++) {
  return funcs.push(changeProdBtnAndClick(i));
} 

for (var j = 0; j < productList.length; j++) {
  return funcs[j]();                        
}
```

How this code suppose to looks like?

Comment: `funcs` array contains the returned value, actually which is not returning anything

Comment: If you want to link things together links this you might want to add some `return`'s in there. Also `funcs` is defined as an empty array and I don't see you pushing/appending to it so.....

Comment: @PranavCBalan added your suggestion but still not working, check my main post.

Comment: @NewToJS now I push to array, but this doesn't work

Comment: what is the purpose of second loop.... which doesn't make any sense

Comment: Still its keeping the returned value

Comment: @PranavCBalan to invoke function..

Comment: @MichałLipa : its already invoked at this point `funcs.push(changeProdBtnAndClick(i));`

Comment: @PranavCBalan So how I supposted to write this code?

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is working, if you have a proper DOM element with the class .addProduct set. Here I have added an event handler to listen for the button clicks and then print the button that was clicked out to the log. You can see your attributes being set correctly in the snippet below. Perhaps you are having an issue with your click handler or you haven't set one?

```js
var productList = ['43', '64', '68'];

let btn = document.querySelector('.addProduct');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log( this );
});

for (var i = 0; i < productList.length; i++) {
  btn.setAttribute('itemprop', productList[i]);
  btn.click();
}
```

```html
<button class="addProduct">Button</button>
```

Comment: For me this don't work. Check jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gh1jr5hm/
 this is your code. Check console, you will get 3 times this same item.